# User Session in Oracle Rightnow CX

Tags: php, oracle, rightnow-crm

I'm new to Oracle rightnow CX,

I have added a page called Scheduling in my Customer portal, I don't want to display that page to public. Only a logged in users has to see that page, even in navigation bar also it should not be displayed unless the user is logged in.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `<rn:condition logged_in="true">`

Answer (score 2):

You should review the [OSvC documentation](http://documentation.custhelp.com/euf/assets/docs/may2015/olh/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm?context=crm&topic=developer_guide). It answers many of [these types of questions](https://documentation.custhelp.com/euf/assets/docs/may2015/olh/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm#href=template_page_set.061.79.html&single=true).

You can apply the the `rn:condition` tag to hide the content of your page.  You can also apply this condition to hide and show menus and links on other pages so that only your logged in users see the link.

```
<rn:condition logged_in="true">
```